# How can I make Firefox 4 Sync add-ons

Tags: sync, browser-addons, firefox

As we know [Firefox Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/es-ES/mobile/addon/firefox-sync/) add-on comes installed by default in new Firefox 4 Beta. This add-on allows to sync *bookmarks, passwords, preferencies, histories, tabs,* BUT not *add-on*. 
 It would be perfect to see this feature also, because many of us use it.

Does anybody know any good add-on synchroniser for firefox 4 ?

Answer (score 2):

You need [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/febe/) - though will have to wait till Firefox 4 is out. As on now it supports Minefield ( FF 3.7a4pre)

> FEBE (Firefox Environment Backup Extension) allows you to quickly and easily backup your Firefox extensions. In fact, it goes beyond just backing up -- It will actually rebuild your extensions individually into installable .xpi files. Now you can easily synchronize your office and home browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed both mystifying and slighty annoying, seeing as Chrome's sync feature offers just that.

I would have to test that (just an idea that popped into my head): You could sync your complete Firefox profile folder using a cloud-based folder syncing tool such as Dropbox by placing your Firefox profile folder on both PCs insided the folder synced by Dropbox - you would probably have to rename your profile folders to have the same GUID, but it could totally work.

On googling that mid-way into my trail of thought, I happend upon an [article on Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/272113/sync-your-firefox-extensions-and-profiles-across-computers) that pulls off something like that. It's bit old-ish, so it doesn't include either Dropbox or Firefox sync. I'll try to work out how to do that some time later today in more detail (now that you've brought it up, I'm really curious about getting that to work), but that's the general idea, and I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Siphon - Add-on Synchronizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/siphon-add-on-synchronizer/) instead of Febe.

> Siphon will manage and sync all your Firefox Add-ons with your
>   different computers. It will also save your Add-on list if you ever
>   need to reinstall Firefox.

[image]